# rendering image from storage/app/public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel, image, assets

I have upload my images in laravel using these lines of code :

```
        if($request->hasFile('filea'))

    {   

        $filepath = $request->filea->getClientOriginalName();

        $request->filea->storeAs('public/upload',$filepath);

    }
```

and stored the filename in database.Images are stored successfully in my HDD. When I try to render the image in templates I have used this :

```
<img src="{{ asset('public/upload/'.$user->imagepath) }}/>"
```

this creates this link :

```
<img src="http://localhost:28965/public/upload/IMG_20170906_105035.jpg"/>
```

tried this also :

```
<img src="{{ asset('upload/'.$user->imagepath) }}/>"
```

But no image is rendered. what syntax is wrong here

Comment: You shouldn't be using public with asset() as asset() already uses the web directory.  Hard to know how you have your local web server set up, but the last example should work if you have your APP_URL configured properly and the file exists in public/uploads.

Comment: How to set APP_URL ? in which file ?

Comment: APP_URL should be in your .env file as the url to the root of the application.

Comment: Everything seems to be perfect.APP_URL=http://localhost is written in .env file

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a laravel issue then if your url is fine but the image isn't showing up.  Likely an issue with the web server configuration.

Comment: Is this saving the image in your `storage/app/public`  directory?

Comment: yes.in storage/app/public/upload directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. What happened is this :
I have uploaded image in laravel so it will be stored in 
storage/app/public. But if I try to access to via asset it won't work because asset refers to public folder. So I read the config/filesystems.php which has these lines :

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

So it means that accessing localhost:port/storage will link to storage/app/public folder. So I ran this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And in the image source in rendering I wrote this :

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/upload/'.$user->imagepath) }}" />
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{ asset('upload/'.$user->imagepath) }}">
```

This should work if the file exists in public/uploads and check your APP_URL in .env file.
If your file in your storage Please try:
storage_path('app/public/upload'.$user->imagepath)

Like:

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('app/public/upload'.$user->imagepath) }}">
```

Comment: No luck . Tried this also. URL created for this is :
http://localhost:28965/upload/IMG_20170906_105035.jpg

image is in HDD. but no rendering.

Comment: @Yunus the image is in this path but doesn't render?

Comment: the actual path is like this :

->storage
  ->app
    ->public
       ->upload
           ->IMG_20170906_105035.jpg

Comment: Please try:storage_path('app/public/upload'.$user->imagepath);

Comment: My last comment will help you without changing any config file try it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you created the symbolic link?
, you may use the  storage:link Artisan command:

`php artisan storage:link`